# Magento 2.2.0 admin developer configuration

Tags: magento2.2, configuration, developer-mode

[image]

When I do mode show in my CLI it shows that I've developer mode on but it still wont show developer configuration ? Why is that , Is that removed.

Comment: in my NGINX Settings I've developer mode set, also in my env.php just to make sure if I am missing something but everything is set to developer mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I forgot to clear the cache